# Pandas re-ordering values in Multi-Index columns on a row-by-row basis

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following Multi-Index table:

| A |  |  |  | B |  |  |  | C |  |  |  | D |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **t_1** |  | **t_2** |  | **t_1** |  | **t_2** |  | **t_1** |  | **t_2** |  | **t_1** |  | **t_2** |  |
| **x** | **y** | **x** | **y** | **x** | **y** | **x** | **y** | **x** | **y** | **x** | **y** | **x** | **y** | **x** | **y** |
| *2.2* | 5.1 | 3.4 | 1.8 | *1.5* | 6.7 | 8.1 | 7.5 | *6.1* | 2.1 | 9.3 | 7.1 | *8.2* | 1.1 | 1.4 | 2.5 |
| *7.9* | 3.2 | 1.1 | 5.3 | *9.3* | 3.1 | 0.9 | 3.2 | *4.1* | 5.1 | 7.7 | 4.3 | *8.1* | 0.4 | 2.4 | 4.1 |

Data Points `(x, y)` have been randomly assigned to columns A - D. I want to re-order them by the `x`-value at `t_1` - shown in *italics*. The other values don't matter for re-ordering, but are carried along to their new column by the `x`-value at `t_1`. This means ***each row will be re-ordered differently***.

I want some code which processes the above table to produce:

| A |  |  |  | B |  |  |  | C |  |  |  | D |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **t_1** |  | **t_2** |  | **t_1** |  | **t_2** |  | **t_1** |  | **t_2** |  | **t_1** |  | **t_2** |  |
| **x** | **y** | **x** | **y** | **x** | **y** | **x** | **y** | **x** | **y** | **x** | **y** | **x** | **y** | **x** | **y** |
| *1.5* | 6.7 | 8.1 | 7.5 | *2.2* | 5.1 | 3.4 | 1.8 | *6.1* | 2.1 | 9.3 | 7.1 | *8.2* | 1.1 | 1.4 | 2.5 |
| *4.1* | 5.1 | 7.7 | 4.3 | *7.9* | 3.2 | 1.1 | 5.3 | *8.1* | 0.4 | 2.4 | 4.1 | *9.3* | 3.1 | 0.9 | 3.2 |

Comment: I didn't get the question. Please give more explanation. how you got that result table.

Comment: It seems all x (t_1) are in asc order. and y (t_1) are in desc order.

Comment: @Pygirl I have added some more explanation. Only x(t_1) is used for the sorting, with y(t_1), x(t_2), and y(t_2) values not being relevant, just being 'carried' by the x(t_1) sorting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an option involving mostly meddling with the shape of the data, sorting and then using the re-shaped values and original `df` columns (a MultiIndex) to create the final dataframe:

```py
df2 = df.T.unstack(level=0).T.reset_index(level=0, col_fill='row')
df2 = df2.sort_values([('level_0', 'row'), ('t_1', 'x')], ignore_index=True)
values = df2.drop(('level_0', 'row'), axis=1).values.reshape(2, -1)
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data=values, columns=df.columns)  # using original df's columns
```

Output:

```
                    A                   B                   C                   D
        t_1       t_2       t_1       t_2       t_1       t_2       t_1       t_2
     x    y    x    y    x    y    x    y    x    y    x    y    x    y    x    y
0  1.5  6.7  8.1  7.5  2.2  5.1  3.4  1.8  6.1  2.1  9.3  7.1  8.2  1.1  1.4  2.5
1  4.1  5.1  7.7  4.3  7.9  3.2  1.1  5.3  8.1  0.4  2.4  4.1  9.3  3.1  0.9  3.2
```

In a more readable but inaccurate table format:

| A |  |  |  | B |  |  |  | C |  |  |  | D |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| t_1 |  | t_2 |  | t_1 |  | t_2 |  | t_1 |  | t_2 |  | t_1 |  | t_2 |  |
| x | y | x | y | x | y | x | y | x | y | x | y | x | y | x | y |
| 1.5 | 6.7 | 8.1 | 7.5 | 2.2 | 5.1 | 3.4 | 1.8 | 6.1 | 2.1 | 9.3 | 7.1 | 8.2 | 1.1 | 1.4 | 2.5 |
| 4.1 | 5.1 | 7.7 | 4.3 | 7.9 | 3.2 | 1.1 | 5.3 | 8.1 | 0.4 | 2.4 | 4.1 | 9.3 | 3.1 | 0.9 | 3.2 |

Comment: I was having hard time finding the correct syntax for sorting them by A,B,C,D blocks row element. +1. It looks good

Comment: I will suggest you to use this awesome.tool for showing table:https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables

Comment: @Pygirl Thanks. I generally use `df.to_markdown` when needed but that doesn't handle MultiIndex columns well, at all. The tool you linked gets closer, but would still need to manually adjust the headers, remove the duplicated header labels, etc. which is not ideal. Which is the same issue in OP's table. Hmm, I may add that in if it helps readability.

Answer (score 2):

try with `unstack` and `groupby`: (only solution I can think of right now)

```
df1 = df.unstack().unstack()
for col in df1.columns:
    a = []
    for i,g in df1[col].groupby(level=0):
        a.append((i,g.iloc[0]))
    get_sortedli = sorted(a, key=lambda x: x[1])
    order_col = [f1 for f1,f2 in get_sortedli]
    val = (df.iloc[col].reindex(order_col, axis=1, level=0))
    df.iloc[col] = val
```

---

**df:**

[image]

I have imagined this as a 4 block arrangement(A,B,C,D) problem. After arranging get the values and assign it to the real dataframe.

**df1:**

[image]

Comment: @Benjamin wrt your edit of adding `val.index = df1[col].index` - it's not necessary as you can see, the result is the same without that line. `val`'s index is already that.