# pandas dataframe: swap column headings by index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns

I use pandas dataframe to plot csv. data taken with a spectrometer.

```
df = pd.read_csv("C:\\file.csv") # import file
```

The output table always consists of pairs

| sample 1 | Unnamed:1 | sample 2 | Unnamed:2 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| wavelengths | transmission 1 | wavelengths | transmission 2 | ... |

One column belonging to each sample ('sample 1', 'sample 2',...) where relevant information about the samples is stored in the header, but the column is only containing the wavelength information

One numbered column ('Unnamed: 1', 'Unnamed: 2',...) that actually contains the relevant measured information

I would now like to display the data as a function of the wavelength. If I delete all columns containing the redundant wavelength information by using

```
df = df.drop(data.columns[1,37], axis=1, inplace=False)
```

I lose the information about the samples contained in the heading
I am now thinking about swapping the column headings and then deleting the columns I don't need.
I could of course swap the columns by name using something

```
df[['sample 1','Unnamed: 1']]=df[['Unnamed: 1','sample 1']]
```

but then I would have to enter the names for each new data series that sometimes contain more than 10 paired columns.

Is there a way to swap the headings via index?
Or can you think of a more elegant version? This form of tabular data output, where the header always spans two columns, is certainly not an isolated case.
Thanks a lot

Comment: I didn't get what you actually want. If you need to filter out by using column names Use: `df.filter(like='samp')` <--- this will give all the columns with samp. Please add input and your expected output.

Comment: Does your DataFrame have a single row ?

Comment: do you want something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66581283/pandas-re-ordering-values-in-multi-index-columns-on-a-row-by-row-basis/66582205#66582205 ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean exactly (some mock data in your sample table would be great), but assuming that right now each row is a separate dataframe and each two columns are samples, would something like this work?

```
# sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'sample1':[23.1, 12.2, 15.8],
    'Unnamed:1':['alpha','beta','gamma'],
    'sample2':[12.1, 13.4, 11.1],
    'Unnamed:2':['alpha','beta','gamma'],
    'sample3':[0.1,0.43,0.29],
    'Unnamed:3':['alpha','beta','gamma']
})
```

|  | sample1 | Unnamed:1 | sample2 | Unnamed:2 | sample3 | Unnamed:3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 23.1 | alpha | 12.1 | alpha | 0.1 | alpha |
| 1 | 12.2 | beta | 13.4 | beta | 0.43 | beta |
| 2 | 15.8 | gamma | 11.1 | gamma | 0.29 | gamma |

```
# initiate a blank dataframe
new_df = pd.DataFrame()

# filter columns by the sample number, then append to new_f
n = 3 # number of samples
for i in range(1,n+1):
    temp_df = df[[col for col in df.columns if f'{i}' in col]]
    temp_df.columns = 'wavelength','transmission'
    temp_df['sample'] = i
    new_df = new_df.append(temp_df)
new_df = new_df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

|  | wavelength | transmission | sample |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 23.1 | alpha | 1 |
| 1 | 12.2 | beta | 1 |
| 2 | 15.8 | gamma | 1 |
| 3 | 12.1 | alpha | 2 |
| 4 | 13.4 | beta | 2 |
| 5 | 11.1 | gamma | 2 |
| 6 | 0.1 | alpha | 3 |
| 7 | 0.43 | beta | 3 |
| 8 | 0.29 | gamma | 3 |

All the data relationships are still retained, and you can just do a `new_df.groupby('wavelength').mean()` to find the mean value of each wavelength. Substitute mean with `apply()` and add your own function as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can most easily manipulate the values, instead of the DataFrame as a whole.

Let's say your data is :

```
import pandas as pd
# Example data
df = pd.DataFrame([["sample 1", "Unnamed:1", "sample 2", "Unnamed:2"], [0.614, "transmission 1", 0.68168, "transmission 2"]])
```

|  | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | sample 1 | Unnamed:1 | sample 2 | Unnamed:2 |
| 1 | 0.614 | transmission 1 | 0.68168 | transmission 2 |

Now let's keep the values we want and their column header.

```
vals = df.values
new_df = pd.DataFrame(vals[1,::2], index= vals[0, ::2], columns=["wavelength")
```

new_df now is :

|  | wavelength |
| --- | --- |
| sample 1 | 0.614 |
| sample 2 | 0.68168 |

Answer (score 0):

You can divide the column labels into 2 parts:  even number columns and odd number columns.  Then, swap their sequence within each pair of even-odd numbered columns, as follows:

```
swapped_cols = np.ravel([[y, x] for x, y in zip(df.columns[0::2], df.columns[1::2])])
```

Here, `df.columns[0::2]` and `df.columns[1::2]` contains the even and odd number columns.

```
print(swapped_cols)

['Unnamed:1' 'sample 1' 'Unnamed:2' 'sample 2']
```

**Case 1:** If you want to swap only the column labels, without swapping the column contents, you can do:

```
df.columns = swapped_cols
```

**Result**:

```
print(df)

     Unnamed:1        sample 1    Unnamed:2        sample 2
0  wavelengths  transmission 1  wavelengths  transmission 2
```

**Case 2:** If you want to swap the column sequence (with column labels and column contents swapped together), you can do:

```
df = df[swapped_cols]
```

**Result**:

```
print(df)

        Unnamed:1     sample 1       Unnamed:2     sample 2
0  transmission 1  wavelengths  transmission 2  wavelengths
```